# How to stop Roo from generating Tiles2 definitions?

Tags: spring-roo, tiles

I created a basic Roo application that used Tiles2 by default and used the mvc scaffold command.  I've since decided to upgrade to Tiles3, so have added all the configuration/etc manually.  I then tried to delete all the views.xml files that Roo had generated, as well as the associated views/templates that I don't need/want any longer, but Roo keeps regenerating them everytime the shell opens.

How can I tell Roo to stop generating those files, and to no longer generate anything Tiles2 based?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to strip ROO out of your project completely if that's an option?
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to remove ROO.  I would like to keep it to help generate the other ITDs (ex: getters/setters/entities/etc).  But I just want to eliminate it from generating Tiles2 config files & views.

Answer (score 0):

**Preventing Spring Roo from generating and updating Scaffolding is quite straightforward** and **doesn't need to include removing Roo all together** from the project. The more rewarding method would be to **remove only what you don't need**.

In your case you would **comment out or delete the @RooWebScaffold annotation in the Controller**, after which Roo, if running, would delete the ITD-file "[EntityName]Controller_Roo_Controller.aj" as the methods therein wouldn't be required any more by the controller. If you still would need any of the methods in the controller you could push-in these to the Controller java source prior to deactivating the annotation. 
Roo would also update or delete (if  empty) the ITD-file "ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj"(1). **The generated scaffolding(1) must be removed by hand.**

(1) Please note that would you decide to reactivate scaffolding for this Controller you might need to restart Roo to have the scaffolding and ConversionService ITDs regenerated.